# Facebook ad -> conversion tracking for multiple adsets

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk, ads

I wish to run multiple Facebook ad sets. One function to track the conversion: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/ios#events

Will a conversion from any of the ad sets increase the amount of conversions on all ad sets? Should I only run one ad set at a time?

Comment: did you tried something ?

Answer (score 3):

Ah. It seems the Facebook SDK is intelligent enough to tell users apart. It seems that events are linked to the ad that users came from. Great.